# How to forEach where (angular.js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, foreach, push

In this forEach I push some fields into an existing array.
How can i filter out where prop.isRequired = false?

So: (only) Loop everything in schema.properties, where isRequired = true;

```
 angular.forEach(vm.schema.properties, function (prop,key) {
   vm.mappingFields.push({      //this is an array
     source: null,                //this gets pushed
     destination: key,            //this gets pushed
     fieldType: prop.type,        //this gets pushed
     isRequired: prop.isRequired, //this gets pushed
   });
 });
```

Comment: With a `if` around your `push`.

Comment: @tkausl i used this and it works, thank you. it doesnt feel like the most decent way but it works

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it in modern way like this:

```
  vm.mappingFields = vm.schema.properties.filter({ isRequired } => isRequired).map(prop => {
      source: null,
      destination: key,
      fieldType: prop.type,
      isRequired: prop.isRequired
  })
```

First we use ES6 `Array.filter` method then just `Array.map` to generate new array with needed fields and assign new generated array into `vm.mappingFields`.

Also I used ES6 Destructuring `{ isRequired } => isRequired` to reduce code (`prop => prop.isRequired`) and make it more easy to read.

One more thing is when you generate new array the `isRequired: prop.isRequired` is unnecessary since we know that only elements with `isRequired: true` came here.. so I'd change it to `isRequired: true`

---

Of course you can achieve the same result using `forEach` and `if` condition inside as other contributors mentioned, but that is not as elegant as my answer. But to honest, my method require a slightly more ticks to finish since 2 Array cycles evaluating, but remember we write code for humans, not for machines.

Comment: Thanks Max, but it comes up with =>  (js) ',' is expected

Comment: You're losing the `key` though. You'd have to map first, then filter, to keep the original key.

Comment: @tkausl Oh, yes, thanks.. I haven't really tested it in the browser.. Just an idea

Answer (score 0):

For now I fixed it like this, but this does not seem like the most clean/decent way. If anyone could come up with a better solution I would appreciate it.

```
   angular.forEach(vm.schema.properties, function (prop, key) {
                        if (prop.isRequired == "true") {
                            vm.mappingFields.push({
                                source: null,
                                destination: key,
                                fieldType: prop.type,
                                isRequired: "Required",
                            });
                        };
```